# runtime error when try dynamic array allocation as a function

Tags: c++, qt

when I try to allocate dynamically a matrix like

```
array = new double *[genome_size];
for(int i=0; i<genome_size; i++)
    array[i] = new double[max_size]();
```

there is no problem, and everything is fine, until I tried to make a function to do the job like

```
void createArray(double **array,  int max_size,  int genome_size)
{
    array = new double *[genome_size];
    for(int i=0; i<genome_size; i++)
        array[i] = new double[max_size]();
}
```

and use the function as

```
double **avgWing1;
createArray(avgWing1, max_size, genome_size);
```

I got runtime error. I'm curios why?

any idea appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, you do know this is a terrible way to represent a matrix?

Comment: I don't look for better representation dude, but I like to hear your way @111111

Comment: well firstly you are much better using an ADT, ideally from a numerical library, like boost uBlas or NT2. (They'll provide matrix and vector types). However if you must roll you're own it's much better to have a single `double*` with `m*n` number of elements and then calculate the offset like `array[ j*m + i ]` or whatever have you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you pass the parameter. After you called the method, the value of `avgWing1` has not changed. You need to either return it or pass the parameter as a reference:

```
void createArray(double ** &array,  int max_size,  int genome_size)
//                         ^ here
```

Comment: it worked as you said, but i didn't get the point, why I need a reference when array is a pointer itself?

Comment: @dare When you pass the pointer, the argument is a **copy** of said pointer. You need the reference to tell the compiler that you want, well, a reference to the pointer that is passed. Otherwise the assignment within the function is applied to the copy (the parameter) and not to `avgWing1` and when the function returns, the value of `array` is thereby lost.

Comment: when I call createArray I pass the address, and right know I'm confused.

Comment: @dare Er, no, you don't pass the address. You pass a pointer to a pointer to `double`, `double**` for short, which is not initialized and which is called `avgWing1`. That pointer is copied into *another* `double**` which is called `array`. You then assign a value to `array`. When the function ends, the copy called `array` is thrown away and `avgWing1` is still not initialized. That's exactly why you need to pass a *reference* to the `double**` called `avgWing1`, now the reference is called `array`. When you assign something to `array`, it assigns to the referenced pointer called `avgWing1`.

Comment: @dare Actually, nio's solution is a preferable in your specific example (I gave him a +1), but you still need to understand how pointers, references, etc. work as this will be essential in the future.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41222/discussion-between-dare-and-daniel-frey)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you need to pass pointer to your pointer.:) Something as

```
void createArray(double ***array,  int max_size,  int genome_size)
{
    *array = new double *[genome_size];
    for(int i=0; i<genome_size; i++)
        ( *array )[i] = new double[max_size]();
}


double **avgWing1;
createArray( &avgWing1, max_size, genome_size);
```

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `avgWing1` in your createArray function itself is a variable, that gets passed into createArray function as an argument `double** array` but **by value**...

This means, that inside `createArray` the `double** array` is just a local variable that will be set to value of `avgWing1` and will exist only inside the function. You will allocate the array of double* and store the pointer into the local variable, but once you leave the function, the value will be lost and you would have no way to determine where did you allocate everything. The `avgWing1` will be left with previous value.

The simplest solution for you would be returning the pointer from createArray:

```
double** createArray(int max_size,  int genome_size)
{
    double** array = new double *[genome_size];
    for(int i=0; i<genome_size; i++)
        array[i] = new double[max_size]();
    return array;
}
```

Usage:

```
double **avgWing1 = createArray(max_size, genome_size);
```